# add an option to the read page

Tags: customization, admin-menu

I want to add an option to the static page in the admin read page.
[image]

I want to add a Portfolio page option where the user can select a page to set as portfolio page.

Google helped me somewhat with [this](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-add-settings-section-in-wordpress-default-settings/) code. But that adds an entire new option to the page.

How do I go about adding this option?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's no hook in WordPress that allows you to add a third option there. So you need to add a new option at the bottom as described in that post you linked to. Unless you add something using JavaScript, which I don't recommend.

I think that makes more sense anyway. In the latest version of WordPress, the reading setting says "Your homepage displays …". This is about selecting what to display on the front page, nothing more. Your homepage doesn't display a portfolio page. It display either a static page, or the latest posts. Choosing a portfolio page has nothing to do with that.

That's why I really recommend you to add a separate option at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thnx for you reply. I'm aware that there is no WordPress hook. Was wondering how to create a custom hook. The bottom option is always an option but hoped I could keep it all together.

Comment: Since there's no hook in WordPress in this section of the page, it's impossible to add another option there. Unless you use something hacky like JavaScript DOM manipulation or output buffering, which I don't recommend. You can't "create" a custom hook there without editing core files, which I also don't recommend at all.